# subcaptions for tables can not be displayed

Tags: tables, subcaption

everyone.

For making tables with subcaptions,I write the source as shown below.

However, subcaptions can not be displayed as shown in attached screen shot.

Let me know how to solve it.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{table}

\begin{subtable}
\centering

\begin{tabular}{lll}
\hline
Land cover classes & Producer's accuracy(\%) & User's accuracy(\%)\\

\hline
UBA & 94 & 92 \\

OFA & 79 & 85 \\

FA & 88 & 81 \\

WA & 76 & 81 \\
Overall accuracy & 87 & \\
Kappa coefficient & 0.853 & \\
\hline
%\caption{1985}
\end{tabular}
\caption{1985}

\end{subtable}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{subtable}
\centering

\begin{tabular}{lll}
\hline
Land cover classes & Producer's accuracy(\%) & User's accuracy(\%)\\

\hline
UBA & 93 & 90 \\

OFA & 81 & 88 \\

FA & 83 & 80 \\

WA & 76 & 76 \\
Overall accuracy & 86 & \\
Kappa coefficient & 0.833 & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\caption{1997}

\end{subtable}
\caption{Summary of the results from the classification accuracy assessment conducted}
\end{table}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to specify the `width` for `subtable`. It should be

```
\begin{subtable}{\textwidth}       %% change \textwidth suitably
```

Changing this in your code solves the issue.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{table}

\begin{subtable}{\textwidth}
\centering

\begin{tabular}{lll}
\toprule
Land cover classes & Producer's accuracy(\%) & User's accuracy(\%) \\ \midrule
UBA                & 94                      & 92                  \\
OFA                & 79                      & 85                  \\
FA                 & 88                      & 81                  \\
WA                 & 76                      & 81                  \\
Overall accuracy   & 87                      &                     \\
Kappa coefficient  & 0.853                   &                     \\
\bottomrule
%\caption{1985}
\end{tabular}
\caption{1985}

\end{subtable}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{subtable}{\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\toprule
Land cover classes & Producer's accuracy(\%) & User's accuracy(\%) \\ \midrule
UBA                & 93                      & 90                  \\
OFA                & 81                      & 88                  \\
FA                 & 83                      & 80                  \\
WA                 & 76                      & 76                  \\
Overall accuracy   & 86                      &                     \\
Kappa coefficient  & 0.833                   &                     \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{1997}
\end{subtable}
\caption{Summary of the results from the classification accuracy assessment conducted}
\end{table}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

[image]

I have also changed `\hline`s with `\toprule` etc from `booktabs` package.